Primitive array Type in Kotlin
I have a Java library with a function like this:
fun f(t: java.lang.reflect.Type)

Now, I want to check, if the type is an array of bytes. So I'd do something like this:
override fun f(t: Type) {
  if (t == ByteArray::class) doSomething()
}

But the condition fails!
If I try to println(t) I get byte[]. But println(ByteArray::class) is class [B. (And it's the same if I use ::class.java.)
So, how can I check for these primitive arrays in Kotlin?

Just to confirm, Type is java.lang.reflect.Type right?

What does println(t::class) print? It is probably not java.lang.Class.

Yes, it is java.lang.reflect.Type.

You need if (t == ByteArray::class.java). https://pl.kotl.in/3IcUpc6eg

println(t::class) gives class libcore.reflect.GenericArrayTypeImpl (Kotlin reflection is not available)

If t is a GenericArrayType, check if t.genericComponentType == Byte::class.java.

Yes! if ((type as? GenericArrayType)?.genericComponentType == Byte::class.java) works!

if ((t as? GenericArrayType)?.genericComponentType == Byte::class.java)


You might want to add a check for non-generic arrays too (t == ByteArray::class.java), just in case.

fun f(t: java.lang.reflect.Type) {
  if (t is Class<*> && t.isArray && t.getComponentType() == Byte::class.javaPrimitiveType) {
    println("hhh")
  }
}

